Como solucionar ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT al implementar Paypal en una aplicacion web
He implementado PayPal en mi aplicación web con angular y todo "funciona bien" pero al intentar hacer una compra a través de PayPal me salta el siguiente error
js?client-id=AdEiqlo…y=EUR&commit=true:3
POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger?disableSetCookie=true net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
. He probado tambien desactivando todas las extensiones , en distintos navegadores como Brave y Google Chrome, borrando la cache del navegador pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.
. He buscado pero no encuentro ninguna solución. Así es como hago la solicitud.
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgIf} from "@angular/common";
import {IPayPalConfig, ICreateOrderRequest, NgxPayPalModule} from "ngx-paypal";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-gateway',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NgIf,
    NgxPayPalModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './payment-gateway.component.html',
  styleUrl: './payment-gateway.component.css'
})
export class PaymentGatewayComponent implements OnInit{

  public paypalConfig?: IPayPalConfig;
  private cargoReserva: number = 10;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.initConfig()

  }

  private initConfig() {

    this.paypalConfig ={

      currency: 'EUR',
      clientId: 'AdEiqloW23xMJLhk-BDHO0UmOSsIhJi1qqMioC7VGjH0S6ssPkNLFgrSxXSJVNcd9EqFkVEpVjGW0_UT',
      createOrderOnClient: () =>
        <ICreateOrderRequest>{
        intent: "CAPTURE",
          purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {

              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: this.cargoReserva.toString(),
              breakdown: {
                item_total: {
                  currency_code: 'EUR',
                  value: this.cargoReserva.toString()
                },
              },
            },
            items:[
              {
                name: 'Reserva Horizonte Dorado',
                quantity: '1',
                category: 'DIGITAL_GOODS',
                unit_amount: {
                  currency_code: 'EUR',
                  value: this.cargoReserva.toString()
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
        },
      advanced:{
        commit: 'true',

      },
      style: {
        label: 'paypal',
        layout: 'vertical',
      },
      onApprove: (data,actions) => {
        console.log('onAprove - transaction was aproved, but not authorized',
          data,
          actions
        );
        actions.order.get().then((details: any) => {
          console.log('onApprove - you can get full order details inside Approve: '
          ,details
          );
        });
      },
      onClientAuthorization: (data) => {
        console.log(
          'onClientAuthorization - you should probably inform your server about completed transaction at this point',
          data
        );
      },
      onCancel: (data,actions) => {
        console.log('onCancel',
          data,
          actions
        );
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.log('onError',
          err
        );
      },
      onClick:(data,actions) => {
        console.log('onClick',
          data,
          actions
        );
      },

    };

  }


}

